# Outlook Mail loads background image only on click

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, vml

I've been struggling with this for a while now and I can't get any answer.

I wanted to use background image in the email template which works fine on all email clients like gmail, yahoo, etc using background attribute on HTML table. But this fails on Outlook Desktop Email.
So for this I used VML and was able to do that.

But the issue with this is that the background image loads only after clicking the background area.

```
<table width='600' height='800' align='center' style='min-hwight:800px;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
    <td background='[background-image]' bgcolor='#baeef7' width='600' height='800' valign='top' align='center'>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <v:rect xmlns:v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml' fill='true' stroke='false' style='width:600px;height:800px;'>
        <v:fill type='tile' src='[background-image]' color='#baeef7' />
        <v:textbox inset='0,0,0,0'>
        <![endif]-->
        <div>
            <table align='center' width='600' height='800' style='width:600px;height:800px' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                <tr height='80'>
                    <td width='175' style='width:175px;text-align:right;' align='right'>
                        Header Image
                    </td>
                    <td width='250' style='width:250px;'></td>
                    <td width='175' style='width:175px'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width='175' valign='bottom' style='width:175px'><img src='https://www.subsource.com/ContentPages/images/template-1-175.png' alt='' /></td>
                    <td width='250' height='160' valign='middle' style='padding:0 7px;width:250px'>
                        <span style='font-size:36px;text-align:left;color:#fff;text-transform:uppercase;display:block; font-family: Myriad Pro, Gill Sans, Calibri, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;letter-spacing: 1px;'>
                            Some Text HERE 
                        </span>
                        </td>
                    <td width='175' style='width:175px' valign='bottom'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr height='250'>
                    <td width='175' style='width:175px'>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style='width:250px;height:250px;text-align:center;width:175px' height='250' width='250' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                       <div style='background-color: #FFFFFF;margin:0;padding:0;width:250px;height:250px;'>
                           Image Here
                        </div>  
                    </td>
                    <td width='175' style='width:175px'>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width='175' valign='top' style='width:175px'>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width='250' valign='top' style='width:250px;color: #119346; text-align: left; font-family: Myriad Pro, Gill Sans, Calibri, sans-serif;padding:0 7px'>

                        <div style='font-size: 30px;line-height:1; font-family: Myriad Pro, Gill Sans, Calibri, sans-serif;text-transform:capitalize;font-weight:bold;'>Hello Abc</div>
                        <div style='font-size: 17px;line-height:1;margin-top: 4px;font-family: Myriad Pro, Gill Sans, Calibri, sans-serif;text-transform:capitalize;font-weight:bold;'> Address: 123 456 798 789  </div>
                        <div style='font-size: 15px;line-height:18px; font-family: Myriad Pro, Gill Sans, Calibri, sans-serif;margin-top:5px;'> Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here. Some text goes here.
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td width='175' valign='top' style='width:175px'>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width='175' height='65' style='width:175px'></td>
                    <td width='250' height='65' style='width:250px'></td>
                    <td width='175' height='65' style='width:175px'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr height='30'>
                    <td colspan='3'>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>  
        </div>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
    </v:rect>
    <![endif]-->
    </td>
</tr></table>
```

Please suggest me some solution. This is the requirement that I need to fulfill.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried the same VML in a smaller part of the template? Is it still doing the same? Personally i have never had this happen to me. Which outlook are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try eliminating all the `valign` `align` from your code.
Do not use `bgcolor` but `background-color` instead.

This solved my problem once i had the same problem. It worth a try.

Comment: Valign works on emails. Don't think that will be causing issues.

Comment: Unable to fix this issue using this solution.